# Why am I getting a type error in my code?

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

I am trying to write a vigenere cipher code. My psuedo for this is :
- find the index for each letter in plaintext 
- find the index for each letter in the key message 
- add together the indexes 
- new letters will be at the position of the sum of the indexes

I believe I got my code correctly organized but I'm not sure if I'm missing something because I'm getting a type error.

```
# global constants:
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ALPHABET_SIZE = len(ALPHABET)

# main function definition:
def main():
    # User interface:
    print("Welcome to the Vigenere Cipher!")

    keep_running = True

    while(keep_running):
        print("Enter 1 to encrypt a message")
        print("Enter 2 to decrypt a message")
        print("Enter 0 to exit")
        print()

        user_choice = int(input("What would you like to do? " ))

        if user_choice == 0:
            keep_running = False

        if user_choice == 1:
            plaintext = input("Enter a plaintext message to encrypt: ")
            key = str(input("Enter a message to use as the key: "))
            ciphertext = enc(key, plaintext)
            print("Resulting cipertext:", ciphertext)
            print()


        if user_choice == 2:
            ciphertext = str(input("Enter a ciphertext message to decrypt: "))
            key = str(input("Enter a message to use as the key: "))
            plaintext = dec(key, ciphertext)
            print("Resulting plaintext:", plaintext)
            print()


def enc(key, plaintext):
    ciphertext = []
    for cipher_char in plaintext:
        char_pos = ALPHABET.index(cipher_char)
    for key_char in key:
        message_pos = ALPHABET.index(key_char)
    new_pos = (char_pos + key_char)
    enc_char = ALPHABET(new_pos)
    plaintext += enc_char
    return plaintext






# call to main:
main()
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us which line gives the error?

Comment: Don't use `while keep_running:`, it's an anti-pattern. Use `while True:` and then use `break` to stop the loop.

Comment: `ALPHABET(new_pos)` is not valid. `ALPHABET` is a string, not a function. I suspect you meant `ALPHABET[new_pos]`. You also need to deal with `new_pos` being too large, and wrap it around.

Answer (score 1):

The error is at this line

```py
new_pos = (char_pos + key_char)
```

char_pos is a position and is of type int. key_char is a character and is of type string. You can't add one to the other.

Also in these lines directly above:

```py
    for cipher_char in plaintext:
        char_pos = ALPHABET.index(cipher_char)
    for key_char in key:
        message_pos = ALPHABET.index(key_char)
```

Each of the for loops set the variables (char_pos and message_pos respectively) over and over again. So only the positions of the last character in each string (plaintext and key respectively) in the alphabet are taken into account. So you need to rethink the logic somewhat.

Finally I suggest you include upper case characters in ALPHABET. I got a value error the first time I tried it because I tried upper case input.

Comment: You should explain how to fix the bad line. `key_char` should be `message_pos`

Comment: This is true, but still won't make the code work. There are other problems to fix as well so I settled for just answering the question. I hope that ajn will spend some more time thinking and learning.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I am VERY new to this so I really appreciate the advice on what to do and such.